# Unable to build a helper from two images

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/k8XCP/1/ where I'm trying to create a helper that consists of the original thumb being dragged plus an image that shows the user a tip. It's trying to work, but it has two problems:

1. The combined helper being dragged (newHelper) starts off where the newHelper div was laid down, even though I try to set the newHelper offset to the e.clientX/e.clientY of the click. I'd like the helper to start where the thumb is.
2. After I drop the helper, the original thumb in the gallery div is gone, and dragging has broken so that I can't drag the second image.

I build the newHelper with

```
 function buildHelper (){  
         $(this).prependTo('#newHelper'); // this keyword is the thumb
         return $('#newHelper');
 }
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *buildHelper* function to work as expected, it has to return a clone of the original element that you want to drag + clone of #newHelper .
I think there are better solutions to this problem, but for your example this will work;

```
function buildHelper() {
    return $("#newHelper").clone().append($(this).clone());
}
```

You can view an example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/EXQhx/

Comment: When you define a function for the helper property jqueryUI treats anything that is returned from that function as a "clone" object. But the "clone" object will be deleted once your widget is done with it.
So in your original example #newHelper disappears because jQueryUI assumes that it's just a temporary helper object and is not longer needed. That's why you have to clone it. 
A much better solution would be a [tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) , instead of an image. 
Good luck !

Comment: The tooltip would have to be applied only to the thing that was being dragged since the thumbs in the gallery already have a large tootip: "Double-click to crop. Delete at upper right corner." Could I apply a separate tooltip to what's being dragged?  Also, toottips appear when you hover.  We're dragging here.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, ok i get it. In that case you can keep the solution that you have. Because i think this is more a usability/UX issue without a single, right answer and i'm not that good at those things.
Good luck and glad i could help !